# Ice-cream scoop on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, food, melacha-creative-work

Is there anything wrong with using an ice-cream scoop to dish ice-cream on Shabbat? I have been told in the name of a Rebbetzin that you can't.

[image: ice-cream scoop]

Comment: using the scooper on its own, or dipping it into a cup of hot water in between each scoop?

Comment: @Menachem On its own. I know that cooking the ice-cream is not allowed.

Comment: see this forum thread, which discusses the issue and brings a quote from Shmirat Shabbat Ke'Hilchata that one may not shape food on shabbat. I don't have access to the sefer, so can't look it up: http://www.imamother.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=142230 - however, based on the thread, it would seem that the issue is shaping, not scooping.

Comment: Thanks @Menachem! I'm afraid I just couldn't think of a reason why not to use it, but if you are making a shape out of the food it seems some say it's forbidden. If you put your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I don't have the sources to check it up. A post on a forum does not an answer make (in my opinion). If you do have the sefarim, write it up. Also, there might be halachic differences between eggs (which retain their shape) and ice cream (which will quickly start melting).

Comment: I have seen one used in many a (legit) tamid chacham's home. Not sure if that qualifies as an answer though.

Comment: if the issue is shaping, the problem would be the same for any spoon in ice cream, wouldn't it? does it depend on the type of scoop (with a special lilquid in the handle, with a contraption to release the scoop etc)? We had an ice cream kiddush at shul (a YI shul) and used scoopers. Not a great ra'ayah, but...

Comment: @Dan, some things (sometimes _borer_, sometimes _tochen_) depend for their forbidenness on the use of specialized contraptions. I have no idea whether that's relevant here.

Comment: I don't know anyone who goes out of their way to make a series of beautifully perfect spheres of ice cream.  I'm not sure even if they did that it would be prohibited, as spheres might be too simple.  This shaping business is for things where a picture of something is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rabbi Shlomo Perl Shlita](http://www.seetorah.com/Shiur246%20RavPearl.pdf) concludes that you may use a ice cream scoop on Shabbos.

Rabbi Shimon Eider Zatzal in Hilchos Tochen page 217 also allows the use of a scoop on Shabbos.

Comment: R' Shlomo Perl is not talking about an ice cream scoop specifically, but scooping things in general. It is possible that even some of the opinions he brings that forbid scooping would agree that scooping ice cream is permissible. It is certainly not "Gathering" and perhaps not even "Building" since it won't last.